# Entity Framework Entity not Auto-Populating Object on Save

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following classes:

```
public class Order
{
    public Order() { LineItems = new List<OrderLineItem>(); }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    ..  
    public virtual ICollection<OrderLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
    ..
}


public class OrderLineItem
{
    public int OrderLineItemID { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}

 public class Product
 {
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

When I persist Order, I have set the OrderLineItems to the appropriate field. However, after I have saved it to the database with the following code:

```
    public void SaveOrder(Order ord)
    {
        if (ord.OrderID == 0)
        {
            context.Orders.Add(ord);
        }
        else
        {
            var currentCat = context.Orders.Find(ord.OrderID);

            if (currentCat != null)
                context.Entry(currentCat).CurrentValues.SetValues(ord);
            else
                context.Entry(ord).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The OrderLineItem.Product object is null. It has the appropriate ProductID set, but it doesn't populate the actual product. I have tried a few different mappings similar to the following, but I'm a bit new to entity framework.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLineItem>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.Product);
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to iterate through the products and Add() them as well.